# System cannot find Gradle cache.properties

Tags: android

I am using Android Studio 2.2.3.And also new to android programming.
My error is

> `C:\Users\admin\.gradle\caches\jars-1\cache.properties(The system cannot find the file specified).`

Comment: We need to see your `dependencies`.

Comment: Please post your gradle file

Comment: @John not same error

Comment: Is Android Studio being run as administrator? If so, why?